# Has anyone had experience with the Freescale HCS12 Flash Driver for EEPROM Emulation source code?

Tags: embedded, driver, eeprom, 68hc12

... and actually had it working, and changed the length of the data record to something **larger** than the 2 bytes that its demo comes with?

It's a bunch of code to talk to the on-chip DFlash, emulating EEPROM pages, in the Freescale HCS12 range of microcontrollers.

I'm having some real difficulty changing some of the configuration values. However, if I leave all the settings are they came from the demo, it does work.

Comment: \[[tag:flash]\] is Adobe Flash, the web video player, on this site.  You might also be interested in [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com), where [this tag](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/flash/hot) means what you thought it meant.

Comment: Hi cheers kev, yeah I realise that after the little icon came up on the tag. I'll keep it in normal stackexchange because it's most definitely a software question. Not an electronics question.